# track the value changes in queue - java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I am trying to get the track of value in queue.
explaining the problem: 
Ticketing process, where one man can buy one ticket at a time, if he wants to buy more tickets, he has to go back in the queue. I have implemented it but stack to track a value whenever it changes. 
I have a queue [6,1,3,5,2] and I have to track a value at position=4 i.e. value 5 in queue. so I am removing the value and decrements it and again adding back to the queue till it becomes zero.
I want to know when the value at position 4 becomes zero, if I follow the same process. I tried

```
int[] arr = {6,1,3,5,2};
int position =5;
Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    q.add(arr[i]);
    m.put(i,arr[i]);
}
//int s =q.size();
System.out.println("queue = "+q );
int count=0;
int z = m.get(p-1);
int v = p-1;
while(z>=0){
int e = q.remove();
if(e!=0){
    count++;
e--;
q.add(e);
}
int s=q.size();
if(count==v){
    v=v+s;
    z--;
}
}
System.out.println("result = "+ count);
```

it's not given the proper result. I guess, I can use a map to track it, but how I am confused. Thank you in advance for the guidance. 
Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: it would be more easier to understand if you could provide more detailed problem description

Comment: What does the data in your queue represent? The quantity of particular tickets?

Comment: I have an array which represents how many tickets each person in the queue wants to get and you want to determine how many times (persons) the one you're tracking has to wait until he can get all the tickets he wants, in efficient way.

Comment: suppose if we are tracking a person at position 5 in arr={6,1,3,5,2},  arrays represent the number of ticket. First it will get one ticket then again he has to come in queue, till he will get all the tickets. so how long it will take to get all the tickets for person at position 5 ? assume getting 1 ticket = 1 sec for each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an array which represents how many tickets each person in the queue wants to get and you want to determine how many times (persons) the one you're tracking has to wait until he can get all the tickets he wants.

If that is the case you can determine that using something as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {6,1,3,5,2};
    int position = 5;
    int times = arr[position - 1];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (times * arr.length); i++){
        if(arr[i % arr.length] != 0){
            arr[i % arr.length] = arr[i % arr.length] - 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Count: " + count);
}
```

This is not as efficient because it always loop the entire length of the array even though some persons already got all their tickets but it is definitely easier to understand.

Here is an example using a queue to reduce the number of iterations:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {6,1,3,5,2};
        int position = 5;
        Queue<Person> queue = new LinkedList<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            queue.add(new Person(i+1, arr[i]));
        }
        int count = 0;
        while(true){
            Person p = queue.remove();
            p.tickets--;
            count++;
            if(p.tickets == 0){
                if(p.position == position){
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                queue.add(p);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    }

    static class Person{
        int position;
        int tickets;

        public Person(int position, int tickets){
            this.position = position;
            this.tickets = tickets;
        }
    }       
}
```

What this does is to create a queue of persons and loop through that queue until the tracked person gets all its queue. At each iteration the person at the front of the queue is removed from the queue and only added back if he still needs to get tickets `person.ticket != 0`. The iteration stops when the tracked person got all its tickets `person.position == position && person.tickets == 0`.

Comment: Thank you @Titus for the solution. you are correct it's not efficient and we do not want the person come again in the queue, if he has got all the ticket.

Comment: @HiteshKumar I've edited my answer to include an example that uses a queue.